# What's an efficient way to determine all common ancestors of two nodes in a directed graph?

Tags: graph, directed-graph

Let *G* be a directed graph, which may contain cycles, and let *m* and *n* be two nodes in this graph. I'm interested in finding all nodes *a* in *G* such that there are paths leading both from *a* -> *n<sub>1</sub>* -> *n<sub>2</sub>* ... -> *n* and also *a* -> *m<sub>1</sub>* -> ... -> *m*. The set of *a* nodes could be considered the common ancestors of *n* and *m* for my application (cycles and "I'm my own grandpa" nonwithstanding).

My first witless approach is to perform a depth-first search on the predecessor edges of *n* and *m*, traversing the graph and collecting all visited nodes in sets (*O(n)*). I then perform the intersection of those two sets (*O(n)*), resulting an expected *O(n)* complexity.

Before I implement this, I want to make sure this is an efficient way to go about things. My graphs can have tens or even thousands of nodes, and although they are sparse, the algorithm needs to be fast enough to be interactive (i.e. < 0.1 seconds).

Comment: you could "prune" your search for one of the searches as soon as you find 1 common ancestor on a path.  Because once you do, then obviously all ancestors of _that_ common ancestor node will be the same.

Comment: I think your idea is as efficient as it can get, since you have to check the ancestors of `m` and `n` in any case, and their intersection is not longer. Since you are marking visited nodes, cycles shouldn't be a problem. +1 for the question and built in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have been waited with bated breath: I went with my own suggestion above. Performance appears adequate up to 10000 nodes.